# Read size-limited input line ignoring the tail part

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

Is there a library function to read a line of input from stdin with the following requirements?

1. I have a limited static buffer of specific size (size may be a known constant).
2. No dynamic allocation allowed. So the library functions like getline() cannot be used.
3. For lines whose length is beyond the buffer size, the unread tail part of the line is to be ignored.

My solution to read a line is using `fgets` and a loop to read and ignore the tail part. The code is as below

```
char buffer[80], tail_buffer[80];
char * line, * tail;
line = tail = fgets(buffer, 80, stdin);
/* Read the tail part to ignore it */
while (tail != NULL && tail[strlen(tail)-1] != '\n')
{
    tail = fgets(tail_buffer, 80, stdin);
}
/* Use 'line' as needed */
```

Comment: I wouldn't say your solution is really elegant for a few reasons, one of them being that you're using `while(!feof(stdin))`, which is [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Try posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Linus What is wrong with !feof(stdin)? I use this because the end character may not be '\n' on EOF. But this may be unnecessary, as the next invocation of fgets will anyway return NULL.

Comment: @jayant No code review needed here. I just need to understand if there is a library function similar to getline() that reads a complete line into a limited buffer by truncating the tail part.

Comment: "I am trying to find a better solution". That's for codereview.

Comment: @WeatherVane I rephrased my question. Does this still sound like a need for code-review?

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the documentation of scanf, I found a solution myself.

```
char buffer[80];
scanf(" %79[^\n]%*[^\n]", buffer);
```

EDIT: With the comments from @chux that this has some limitations in parsing the blank lines and initial spaces, and with the solution from @user3386109, I enhance this as below to scan all the lines till EOF.

```
char buffer[80] = "";

while (scanf("%79[^\n]%*[^\n]", buffer) != EOF)
{
    /* Process the line in buffer */

    if (feof(stdin)) break;
    getchar(); /* Remove end of line */
    buffer[0] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `%80` should be `%79`. also The beginning of the space is discarded.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I understand the limitation. But for now, I can assume that blank lines are not needed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I do not understand what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, That's the reason why I added a space in front for format string. Any suggestions to improve?

Comment: `" %79[^\n]..."` will ignore leading white-space in a line, so input like `"\t123"` ignores the leading `'\t'`.  Ignoring leading white-space in not mentioned as allowable in the post.

Comment: @chux That's true. This solution isn't good in handling initial space or blank lines.

Comment: From [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485153/read-size-limited-input-line-ignoring-the-tail-part/33485671?noredirect=1#comment54756515_33485671), there is nothing in the post to suggest blank lines are not needed.

Comment: @chux I agree. I do not still accept this as the correct solution according to the problem statement.

Comment: I think probably operation is desired by one of scanf (or one sentence) that's impossible.

Comment: With the new `char buffer[80]; scanf("%79[^\n]%*[^\n]", buffer), getchar()`, should the first `char` be `'\n'`, nothing is save in `buffer` and likely will cause a problem when subsequent code uses an uninitialized buffer.  Robust code does not use `scanf()`.

Comment: @chux :-). I try to initialize buffer before the scanf.

Comment: @chux If I drop `&&` and press Ctrl-D at the beginning of line, then getchar() is waiting for an additional Ctrl-D. There are still some issues with EOF after entering partial line and pressing Ctrl-D, that I may need to fix.

Comment: The latest looks OK - except for 1 tiny hole - should you care - it is obscure.  Code does not use the reason for `scanf()` return.  `scanf()` returns `EOF` under 2 conditions: end-of-file and input error.  With input error, the value of `buffer` is indeterminate.  So any attempt to pre-load `buffer` with a value like `buffer[0]=0` is moot when `EOF` is returned and code does not check `feof()` / `ferror()`.  IOWs do not use `buffer` when an input function returns `EOF`.

Comment: @chux, Thanks, I understand. I think it is easy to ensure that after EOF from scanf, buffer is not processed. I will edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` has corner cases that preclude using it at a complete solution to OP's goal.
Simply loop using `fgetc()`.

```
// Return count of `char` read - not including potential \n.
int read_line(char *dest, int size) {
  int i = 0;
  if (size > 0) {
    size--;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      if (i < size) {
        dest[i++] = ch;
      }
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    if (ch == EOF && i == 0) return EOF;
    }
  return i;
}
```

---

A forced use of `fgets()` looks like

```
bool was_there_extra(char *buf, size_t size) {
  char *lf = strchr(buf, '\n');
  if (lf) {
    *lf = '\0';  // optional: lop off potential trailing \n
    return false;
  }
  int ch;
  bool extra = false;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    extra = true;
  }
  return extra;
}

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  if (was_there_extra(buf, sizeof buf)) ...
  else ...
}
```

This approach does get fooled if code reads a `'\0'`.

Comment: I am not looking for \n in buffer. But need to read and ignore the remaining unread part of the line.

Comment: Appreciate another solution using fgetc(), which doesn't need tail_buffer.

Comment: @user1969104 To be clear, neither answer here uses a tail buffer other than an `int`.  `read_line()` is not for reading the tail buffer, it is for reading the line.

Comment: I understand, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `scanf` to read until the newline is found, and the `getchar` to read the newline.

```
char buffer[80];
if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) != NULL )
{
    if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL )   // if the buffer does not contain the newline
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );                 // read up to the newline
        getchar();                          // read the newline
    }
}
```

Comment: That's sounds like a feasible solution. May be you can try using only scanf and getchar and not mixing it with fgets, like as in `scanf("%79[^\n]%*[^\n]", buffer); getchar();`

Comment: Corner case: `strchr( buffer, '\n' )` only reads `buffer` to the `'\0'` which may be before the `'\n'` if `fgets()` read a null character.  Unusual to find a null character in user input, but it is a hacker's  crack.

Comment: I think there is no need to check for '\n' to determine whether to read tail or not, if we read buffer through scanf itself. This is because, even for the case when there is no tail (everything read into buffer), `%*[^\n]` will just parse empty.

Comment: @chux You are correct that having a null character in the input can cause a line to be skipped, but has no other ill effects.